# How do you enforce your PHP method arguments?

Tags: php, parameters, methods

How do you validate/manage your PHP method arguments and why do you do it this way?

Comment: What does "enforce" mean? Are you speaking about type hinting (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php)?

Comment: Validation in PHP? *confused look*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, assuming that you're talking about type-checking method arguments, it depends:

1. If it's expecting an object, I use [type-hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) with an interface:

   ```
   public function foo(iBar $bar)
   ```
2. If it's expecting an array only, I use type-hinting with the `array` keyword.

   ```
   public function foo(array $bar)
   ```
3. If it's expecting a string, int, bool or float, I cast it:

   ```
   public function foo($bar) {
       $bar = (int) $bar;
   }
   ```
4. If it's expecting mixed, I just check in a cascade:

   ```
   public function foo($bar) {
       if (is_string($bar)) {
           //handle string case
       } elseif (is_array($bar)) {
           //...
       } else {
           throw new InvalidArgumentException("invalid type");
       }
   }
   ```
5. Lastly, if it's expecting an iterable type, I don't use type-hinting.  I check if it's an array first, then re-load the iterator:

   ```
   public function foo($bar) {
       if (is_array($bar)) {
           $bar = new ArrayIterator($bar);
       }
       if (!$bar instanceof Traversable) {
           throw new InvalidArgumentException("Not an Iterator");
       }
   }
   ```
6. If it's expecting a filename or directory, just confirm it with `is_file`:

   ```
   public function foo($bar) {
       if (!is_file($bar)) {
           throw new InvalidArgumentException("File doesn't exist");
       }
   }
   ```

I think that handles most of the cases.  If you think of any others, I'll gladly try to answer them...

Comment: Thanks i was looking for a bunch of examples like this.

Answer (score 2):

Typechecking is something you should do at the development stage, not in production. So the appropriate syntactic feature for that would be:

```
 function xyz($a, $b) {
     assert(is_array($a));
     assert(is_scalar($b));
```

However I'll try to avoid it, or use type coercion preferrably. PHP being dynamically typed does quite well adapting to different values. There are only few spots where you want to turndown the basic language behaviour.

Comment: Valid, but not great.  See [the docs on `assert`](http://us3.php.net/assert) and read this excerpt: `Assertions should not be used for normal runtime operations like input parameter checks. As a rule of thumb your code should always be able to work correctly if assertion checking is not activated.`  But if for debugging only, then it can work...

Comment: @ircmaxell: That's what I meant with `Typechecking is something you should do at the development stage, not in production`. If there is a need to still check types at runtime, then I would surmise more severe structural problems; for which typechecking is unlikely to be a cure. This stuff should be detected while developing (which I would notionally liken to the compile stage for strictly typed languages). So it should indeed count as the long arm of debugging or unit testing.